# How can I make a bayer image and become a debayer again? (demosaicing)

Tags: python, image, opencv, raw, demosaicing

My goal is to blur the picture a bit using a bilinear debayer.

This is to embody the dirty image of the VHS days.

As a graphic major, I tried to reproduce it with various graphic tools, but did not get the desired quality result.
I want that subtle feeling of faded haze when scanned with a scanner.
I decided to emulate a camera sensor.

The process I envisioned is this:
I convert the tiff,targa.png.jpg format image I made into a bayer format image. I want to restore the original image by debayering it again with a bilinear algorithm.

The reason for the bilinear method is that it degrades most gently and strongly.
The link below is the image change according to the algorithm.
https://www.dpreview.com/forums/post/63514167

I'm not a programmer at all, but I've tried something on my own to get what I want.

https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/86410/reverse-bayer-filter-of-an-image
I succeeded in making an image of the Bayer pattern using the coding here.

And I tried debayering by running the debayer source code downloaded from other places, but it failed because the extension was not supported.

So you can change demoasic(debayer) in various ways
I got a program called darkable and raw therapy and tried to convert it, but these programs could only recognize raw files.
Even the algorithms provided by both programs were so good that it was hard to get the impression that the image was degraded.

How do I make what I want?
What can I look for? I really want to make this.

Please let me know which way I should go.

Comment: you tagged OpenCV, so you must know of `cvtColor`. why does that not suit you? oh and "VHS" look isn't due to bayer patterns. it's due to analog recording on a magnetic medium. play around with filters in photoshop. I think you're confused and fixated on the term "bayer" for some reason. it's not what you think.

Comment: I thought you would say so about the vhs effect.To tell the truth, I want to make digital pictures into analog ones. I tried to implement it using Photoshop and After Effects considering all the circumstances. I gained a lot, but I feel a little lacking. It is because of the subtle feeling of scattering of the lens, yes, I also studied and applied cromatic abbration in detail. I also simulated spherical and other aberrations. This is great.

Comment: However, it did not reach the desired result. I have been thinking about the process of vhs. The fact that I am viewing the past vhs images on a pc monitor means that they recorded a video tape with a recording device. That is, they used a digital sensor, and it seems that the blurry image I want will be created by the interpolation technique. This is a very subtle difference, so you may not understand what I'm trying to say.

Comment: I've tried everything I want to implement with Photoshop.And I saw a comparison photo of the image quality deterioration of the interpolation method, and I think I can get what I wanted. Of course, I know that the image of the vhs days cannot be made with this alone. I will work by adding this effect.

Comment: And the reason I tagged opencv is that I only know that it is the latest image processing library.I don't know anything other than that. I only know that someone is doing a debayer using opencv.